# Get number of existing and previous columns for a table

Tags: postgresql

My PostgreSQL installation has a max column count of 1600. It turns this max value is a total for the *lifetime of the table*, so if I add and drop 1601 different columns, one at a time, then I have exceeded the max column count even if the table didn't have more than 1 column at any point.

I want to know if a given table is close to this max. Is there any way I can get the number of current *and previous* columns for a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropped columns are still visible in `pg_attribute`

```
select count(*) filter (where not attisdropped) as active_columns, 
       count(*) filter (where attisdropped) as dropped_columns 
from pg_attribute a
  join pg_class c on a.attrelid = c.oid
where c.relname = 'your_table_name'  
  and attnum > 0; -- this filters out system columns
```